# Unable to download any apps from the Google Play Store

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I can't download any apps from the Google Play Store. I have tried everything but it doesn't work. The download says "paused" on the notifications bar for ever and I can't get it to start.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get Play to connect at all and i found out that the time setting on my device was incorrect, so i set the time correctly and it connected straight away.
Ensure that the time and date is correct on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connected to the internet

Restart your phone and then try again

Otherwise clear the cache for the Play Store in The Applications settings.

Answer (score 0):

Clear all cookies and cache from settings->apps -> all running apps -> open the app -> click on clear data.